# Euler Project problem #12 Python code gives weird results

Tags: python, number-theory

I was trying to solve [problem number 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) of Project Euler. This is the problem:

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural
>   numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7
>   = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> - 1: 1
> - 3: 1,3
> - 6: 1,2,3,6
> - 10: 1,2,5,10
> - 15: 1,3,5,15
> - 21: 1,3,7,21
> - 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five
>   divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five
>   hundred divisors?

I defined two functions to do the job:

1) `allfactor(x)`: This gives us all the factors of a given number in a list form. Example: `allfactor(10)` gives us `[1, 2, 5, 10]`

2)`TriangularNo(x)`: This gives us the nth Triangular number. Example `TriangularNo(5)` gives us `5`

Here is the complete code which I wrote:

```
facs=[]

def allfacof(x):
    for i in range(1,int(x/2)+1):
        if x%i==0:
            facs.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    facs.append(x)
    return(facs)



def TriangularNo(x):
    no=0
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        no=no+i
    return(no)

a=0 # a will tell us the number of iterations

while True:
    a+=1
    N=TriangularNo(a)
    length=(len(allfacof(N)))
    if int(length)>=500:
        print(N)
        break
    else:
        pass
```

When I run this code I get `1378` as the output which is clearly wrong because `len(allfacof(1378))` turns out to be `8` and not `500` as demanded in the question.

Notice in the `while` loop, I use `if int(length)>=500:` So this means that when my code runs, `length` somehow gets the value = 500 but when I run the function separately it says that it's length is 8.

I am just not able to find out the error. Please help me

Comment: Note that TriangularNo(n) is simply n*(n+1)/2 which avoids all the unnecessary looping.

Comment: @Voo Smart! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using `facs` as a global variable and you are only appending to the item. You should make it a member of allfacof() so that it clears out after each value.
If you look into `facs` then you will find it equals

> 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 10 ...

Answer (score 1):

Although moving `facs` into `all_factors_of()` solves your immediate problem, the next problem with this code is performance.  Let's consider triangle number generation first.  The optimization that @Voo suggests:

```
def TriangularNo(n):
    return n * (n + 1) / 2
```

is fine if we're looking for *arbitrary* triangle numbers -- but we're not.  We're looking for *sequential* triangle numbers, so in this case the formula *slows down* our code!  When going sequentially, you only need do a couple of additions to get the next triangle number -- but using the formula, you need to do an addition, a multiplication and a division!  More expensive if you're going sequentially.  Since we *are* going sequentially, this seems a perfect use of a Python generator:

```
def triangular_number_generator():
    triangle = number = 1

    while True:
        yield triangle
        number += 1
        triangle += number
```

Which makes clear the two additions needed to get to the next triangle number.  Now let's consider your factorization function:

Your factorization function loses performance in the way that it produces factors *in order*.  But we're only concerned with the *number of factors*, order doesn't matter.  So when we factor 28, we can add 1 and 28 to the factors list *at the same time*.  Ditto 2 and 14 -- making 14 our new upper limit.  Similarly 4 and 7 where 7 becomes the new upper limit.  So we collect factors faster and quickly reduce the upper limit that we need to check.  Here's the rest of the code:

```
def factors_of(number):
    divisor = 1
    limit = number
    factors = []

    while divisor <= limit:

        if number % divisor == 0:
            factors.append(divisor)

            remainder = number // divisor

            if remainder != divisor:
                factors.append(remainder)

            limit = remainder - 1

        divisor += 1

    return factors

triangular = triangular_number_generator()
number = next(triangular)
factors = factors_of(number)

while len(factors) <= 200:
    number = next(triangular)
    factors = factors_of(number)

print(number)
```

How does it compare?  If we run your fixed code with a lower limit of > 200 factors, it takes about a *minute* to come up with the answer (2031120).  The above code takes about 1/3 of a *second*.  Now consider how long it'll take both to reach > 500 factors.  Finally, to meet the stated goal:

> What is the value of the first triangle number to have ***over*** five
>   hundred divisors?

this comparison in your original code:

```
if int(length)>=500:
```

would instead need to be:

```
if length > 500:
```

Though the way the count of factors jumps, it makes no difference for 500.  But for smaller limits, for testing, it can make a difference.